# Difference between authorized_keys and id_rsa.pub

Tags: rsa

I am experimenting with vagrant and I see that when I run vagrant, the vagrant box already has an `authorized_keys` file in `~/.ssh/`

Inside is an rsa key. What is the difference in this key and if I create an `id_rsa.pub` public key myself using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`id_rsa.pub` is a public key that you add to other hosts' `authorized_keys` files to allow you to log in as that user.  Vagrant has one so it can be added to other hosts' `authorized_keys` files so it can log in automatically.  The one you generated with `ssh-keygen` is for *you* to use, not Vagrant.

`authorized_keys` is a list of public keys that are allowed to log into that specific account on that specific server.

Think of `id_rsa.pub` as a signature for a specific user and `authorized_keys` as a list of authorized signatures who can log into that account on that specific host without a password (assuming they can prove they own the signature).